# DockerImage and command for Azure ML studio singularity training job

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am attempting to start a Singularity training job on Azure ML studio that would open a jupyter notebook and allow me to train my model. But unfortunately I am not sure how to complete the inital setup. What should go in Docker Image and command. Where is the documentation about this process.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can specify the Docker Image and Command:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-with-ui